# Can you fade in a background image whilst keeping child stuff visible?

Tags: html, css, transition

So I have a `<header>` tag with a `<h1>` tag inside it. The `<header>` tag has a CSS background image that I want to slowly fade in using either CSS or jQuery.

```
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
```

Is this possible without fading in the entire `<header>` tag (which will also fade in the `<h1>` tag? I don't want to modify the HTML in any way.

Comment: Not in a cross-browser manner. You need to create a background `<div>` overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children elements inherit the opacity of their parents.

If your background is a colour, you can animate the `background-color` property instead.

If it's not a colour, you can move the children outside of the animating element but then position with CSS so they look like children (or whatever matches your design).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as-is with your `<h1>` being a child node.

If you don't want to modify the HTML, you can use jquery to move the `<h1>` out of the `<header>` and then animate the header separately.

e.g. with something like:

```
$('header:first')
    .find('h1')
        .insertBefore('header:first')
        .end()
    .fadeIn();
```

You'll need to apply CSS rules so that the `<h1>` is positioned over the `<header>` even when it is not a child node.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could `transition` from a Background Color to an image by using:

```
transition: background 5s linear
```

So, for example:

```
#div {
    -webkit-animation:ani 5s;       
    background: url('http://tinyurl.com/cxnemfx');
}

@-webkit-keyframes ani {
from {background: black;}
to {background: url('http://tinyurl.com/cxnemfx');}
}​
```

Demo for Chrome/Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/f32RS/1/

However, you might want to transition from another image to the final image for the full effect. The example is exactly that, and example of what is possible. ;)